# Datagridview only shows column name

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a SQL database with multiple tables and I want to bind one of them to a DataGridView.
I use this code :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx#Y210
But my datagridview only show column names and does not draw any rows.
Does anyone can help me ?

Comment: Are you certain that data is being returned in your data table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see the correct column names but don't see the data, there could be one of these two problems (or both):

1. Your query returns nothing (check in your database manager if there are some data when you execute the query)
2. Your table(s) in the database is empty therefore there is nothing to return.

EDIT: Have you tried switching these two statements?

```
Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
       GetData("select * from Customers"); 
       dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1; 
}
```

Comment: Dear NikolaD
My query is "Select * from Table1" and table is not empty.

Comment: And you see the same column names that you have in Table1?

Comment: I switching them but no difference.Yes,Datagridview columns name is same whit my table columns name.

Comment: Have you checked if the data have been comitted to the database?

Comment: Also, have you changed or added some owner drawing? Try to check in debugger whether you have some data in your DataTable?

Comment: A stupid mistake!
When i use connection string in SqlDataAdapter data base file is :" AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\GhDB.mdf" and when run a query in Visual studio to fill table database path is another ! So,table is empty and Datagridview working properly.

Comment: Well that was obvious, otherwise you wouldn't be getting valid column names. I'm glad that you solved that.